# KMAC algorithm for KeyGenerator in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, hmac

One can generate a symmetric key for use with HMAC-SHA256 with:

```
    String algorithm = "HmacSHA256";
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm);
    keyGenerator.init(256);
    SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
    byte[] key = secretKey.getEncoded();
```

What algorithm name should be used for KMAC?

Comment: Why do you need Keyed Hash function to generate the key? From passwords, one can use PBKDF2, Scrypt, and Argon2. Or use [HKDF](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76588/18298) though not available in JAVA afaik.

Comment: I am looking for a common in Java way to generate a key suitable for use with indicated algorithm, same way this would be done for HMAC-SHA256 (see above), AES etc.

Comment: HMAC key should be uniform random... Why just don't you generate with [SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html)

Comment: I know I could use SecureRandom. I am curious if there is a build-in support for generating such keys using `KeyGenerator.getInstance()`.

Answer (score 1):

KMAC bases on KECCAK/SHA-3 which is [available since Java 9](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/287).

Unfortunately this does only apply to the basic SHA-3 algorithm, not it's [H]MAC implementation (checked in [Java 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/oracle-providers.html)).

In [Java 17](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/security/oracle-providers.html) there the following SHA-3 based Mac implementations are available:

- HmacSHA3-224
- HmacSHA3-256
- HmacSHA3-384
- HmacSHA3-512

If I understand it correctly none of them is equivalent to KMAC. KMAC is a special MAC implementation designed for KECCAK and it's properties.

So the only alternative is a third party implementation of KMAC like the one from BouncyCastle: https://javadoc.io/static/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk14/1.69/org/bouncycastle/crypto/macs/KMAC.html

Comment: If you have the Keccak permutations then it is not hard to implement [KMAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/95723/18298), rather SHAKE-128 uses the KECCAK[256](...).

Comment: I am using that BC library you've mentioned, I am just looking for a simple and typical Java way to generate suitable key using `KeyGenerator.getInstance()`, for use with that BC KMAC implementation.

Comment: @automatictester I am not sure if KMAC is accessible via getInstance method of Mac or KeyGenerator. As you have to use Bouncy castle anyway you can use the class directly as shown in this example: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/test/KMACTest.java